# Ruby's comparator <=> Vs. Java's .equals; to compare Strings

Tags: java, ruby, string, comparison

Her is my ruby script:

```
books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]

puts books.sort! {

  |firstBook, secondBook|

  firstBook <=> secondBook

}
```

I was expecting it would print -1,0 or 1, but it prints book's name. How to get their boolean value in console.

Similarly in Java my code is:

```
public class sampletest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String String1 = "hello";
        String String2 = "Hello";

        System.out.println(String1.equals(String2));
    }
}
```

Here output is: True (a Boolean value)
I am new to Ruby, I don't understand the difference between these two

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you sort (involving lots of comparisons that you don't get to see). In the second example, you just compare. The Ruby equivalent of your Java snippet is:

```
string1 = "hello"
string2 = "Hello"
puts(string1 == string2)
```

Comment: @Amandan comparisons those I cant see are <, = and >. But why I cant see boolean value in console the way it shows in java. How to get boolean value in console and where did write to print book's name in console. Its all confusing please elaborate answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can you please be clearer? You never use `<`, `=`, `>`; you were using a single operator `<=>` which does something different from the three you listed. Ruby prints books' names because you ask it to do so, by invoking `puts` on the result of `books.sort!`. You never print result of comparisons, you are printing an array of books. Given this, why would you expect anything other than array of books to be printed? And, I showed you how to get a boolean value in the console in my answer: print the result of a comparison, not a result of a sort.